# Is there a naming convention for implicit classes?

Tags: scala

For example in Objective-C, where class extensions are direct language construct, we do:

in filed named [*NSArray+FKBinarySearch.h*](https://github.com/futurice/Futility/blob/master/Futility/NSArray%2BFKBinarySearch.h):

```
@interface NSArray (FKBinarySearch)
// ...
@end
```

Do you name your extension classes like:

```
implicit class IndexedSeqBinarySearch[A](seq: IndexedSeq[A]) {
  // ...
}
```

For example scalaz calls makes extensions classes with suffix `Ops`: [BooleanOps](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.0-SNAPSHOT/scalaz_2.11-7.2.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar/!/scalaz/syntax/std/BooleanOps.html) or even extending their own traits [FoldableOps](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.0-SNAPSHOT/scalaz_2.11-7.2.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar/!/scalaz/syntax/FoldableOps.html)

Yet `Ops` feels too general, OTOH there are packages. Also `Ops` in scalaz case contains everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's not really an established convention. @srgfed01 lists some approaches (other conventions I've seen in the wild: implicit conversions for `X` in an object called `ImplicitX` rather than `Implicits`, and `PimpedX` for the implicit class that wraps `X`), but you'll see all of these and more in extant scala libraries - sometimes multiple different conventions in the same library. There's nothing as well-established as the `x2y` style for implicit *conversions*, perhaps because implicit classes are a relatively new feature.

So pick a style you like, and be prepared to look for implicits under many different conventions in the libraries you use.

Comment: Didn't know that *implicit classes* are relatively new. This explains, why there aren't much writings about them.

Answer (score 10):

In [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala) in "Chapter 21 · Implicit Conversions and Parameters" -> "Naming an implicit conversion." it is said:

> Implicit conversions can have arbitrary names. The name of an implicit
>   conversion matters only in two situations: if you want to write it
>   explicitly in a method application, and for determining which implicit
>   conversions are available at any place in the program.

In [Programming Scala](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033073.do) "Chapter 5: Implicits" -> "Wise Use of Implicits" it is said:

> One way to improve implicits visibility is to adopt the practice of
>   putting implicit values in a special package named implicits or an
>   object named Implicits.

Using implicit class is like using implicit method, but in case of class its primary constructor is involved. And if you look at Scala implicit conversion methods results you can find something like:

> - wrapString(s: String): WrappedString
> - genericArrayOps[T](xs: Array[T]): ArrayOps[T]

In my opinion inside `Implicits` object for your implicit class name the following can be used:

> - xOps
> - RichX
> - WrappedX
> - AsX

You may choose any of them which is appropriate to your project conditions.

Comment: Naming implicit conversions is easy, but how to name and structure implicit (extension) classes (or conversion destinations)? Does *Programming in Scala* give any advice on that?

Comment: "Put implicit values in a special package named implicits or an object named Implicits". Of course implicit classes should be placed inside objects.

Comment: Do you propose: `package object Implicits { implicit class ListOps[A](list: List[A]) { /* ... */ } }` ?

Answer (score 1):

The standard lib has `StringOps`.

Someone on the mailing list turned me on to `absurdly descriptive backquoted identifiers` that avoid naming collisions among implicits.

OTOH, maybe you want to make it easy for a client to turn off the implicit by shadowing it.